# Bootstrap table: add data-id to <tr> from remote source

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table with data from remote source, but I can't find how to add data to .
This is my source data:

```
$ajax[] = array(
    "qta" => $row['qta'],
    "name" => $row['name'],
    "description" => $row['description']
);
```

but I would like to have it like:

```
$ajax[] = array(
    "id" => $row['id'], //123
    "qta" => $row['qta'],
    "name" => $row['name'],
    "description" => $row['description']
);
```

in order to have my table row like:

```
<tr data-pk="123">
    <td>...qta...</td>
    <td>...name...</td>
    <td>...description...</td>
</tr>
```

How could I achieve this? Maybe some responseHandler? I'm pretty new to BS Table.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [Data-tables](https://datatables.net/examples/index)

HTML table

```html
<table id="data" class="display table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 1</th>
      <th>Row 2</th>
      <th>Row 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Server side

```js
//List list = new LinkedList();
rs1 = s1.executeQuery("select * from somewhere");
obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("row1", rs1.getString("rowfromdb1"));
obj.put("row2", rs1.getString("rowfromdb2"));
obj.put("row3", rs1.getString("rowfromdb3"));

//list.add(obj);
//return obj;
//return list
```

And JavaScript for Fill in data

```js
//settings for your datatable
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#data').DataTable({
    "columns": [{
      "data": "row1",
      "width": "30%"
    }, {
      "data": "row2",
      "width": "30%"
    }, {
      "data": "row3",
      "width": "40%"
    }]
  });
});
//ajax call which fill up your table on load of your page/change value of some object
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "myScript",
  data: "param1=" + value,
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#data').dataTable().fnClearTable();
    $('#data').dataTable().fnAddData(
      JSON.parse(msg.trim())
    );
  }
}
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I know about DataTables. I could use DT_RowClass for my purpose, but, as the code is not mine, I would like to try to fix it first. If this wont be possible, I will switch to DataTables

Comment: I used a <button> with data-pk attribute already set and returned with the ajax call, because I only need to add a "Delete" button. For more complex tables, I'm still using DataTables